# JavaScript/GWT - requirement to change DIV text created by GWT before page has loaded

Tags: javascript, gwt

I have some HTML where parts of the content are created from GWT. Assume that I have no access to the GWT code, how can I get access to this to modify the content in javascript in the JSP?

My aim is to change DIV text that was genereated with GWT code and I want to change this in the JSP using JavaScript with something like

```
document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "new title";
```

The problem that I have, is the GWT DIVS created seem to be loaded after the body of the JSP has loaded, meaning when I want to access `document.getElementById("title").innerHTML` it doesn't see it, until after the page has loaded?

Comment: Then [wait for the page to load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load)?

Answer (score 0):

> My aim is to change DIV text that was genereated with GWT code

You can achieve it using `GWT JSNI` that is similar to `JavaScript` code.

For detailed descriptions and samples please have a look at [Writing Native JavaScript Methods](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html#writing)

---

Create a JSNI method in your client side JAVA code and call it after creating div.

```
public static native void setTitle(String newTitle)
/*-{
    var title = $wnd.document.createElement("title");
    title.innerHTML = "new title";      

}-*/;
```